# I can't seem to get my form submission to hop files from jsx to js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I am fairly new to react. About 3-4 days spent studying it so far so I might just be doing something stupid. My problem is that I have a form rendered with only a textarea that can be submitted. Right now it is in a jsx file and I am trying to pull it into a js file when the form is submitted. I am using jQuery but I am not getting any errors related to it so I would appreciate if someone could possibly point me in the right direction?

```js
/*---App.jsx file---*/


function Create(){
    let date = new Date().getMonth()+1 + "/" + new Date().getDate() + "/" + new Date().getFullYear();
    const createPost = (
        <div className="createBox">
            <form id="postForm">
                <div className='dateInput'>
                    <label>Date: {date}</label>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div className='commentInput'>
                    <label>Comment: </label>
                    <br/>
                    <textarea type='text' className='commentBox' maxLength='2000'/>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div>
                    <input className='submitInput' type='submit'/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
    return createPost;
}

export default App;



/*---JS FILE---*/



var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

$("#postForm").submit(() => {
    let post = $(".commentBox").val();
    console.log("TEST TEST");
    console.log(post);
});



/*---index.jsx file---*/



import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App/>
);
```

```css
.createBox {
    height: 35vh;
    width: 40vw;
    margin: 7.5% 52.5%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px black;
}

.postForm {
    margin: 1% auto;
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dateInput {
    margin: 3% 5%;
}

.commentInput {
    margin: -4% 5%;
}

.commentBox {
    margin-top: 1%;
    height: 170px;
    width: 96%;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: scroll;
    resize: none;
}

.submitInput {
    margin: 2.5% 42.5%;
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Comment Center - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body id="root">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start simple and slowly add complexity. TDD is good at that.

Comment: I am sorry, what is TDD?

Comment: Test driven development. Contact me directly to continue the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**Opinionated Answer**

Don't use *jquery* when using *react*. Don't use *jquery* at all at this point (2024+) except for learning basic HTML/javascript.

**Educational Answer**

What elements does `$("#postForm")` return at runtime? Add a `console.log($("#postForm"))` and check the developer tools console to see if any elements are in it. I suspect it is length 0 because the form has not been added to the dom yet.

**Potential Solution (Not Tested)**

You could try wrapping it in a *jquery* ready function. All *jquery* code should be in a ready function. But there is no reason for you to use *jquery* if you are using *react*. Even if the project is *react + jquery*, new code should ignore *jquery* altogether and purely use *react*.